# Latex - thousand separator with period but decimal separator with comma?

Tags: siunitx

My question is rather simple:

I want my thousand separator split with period like for example 100.000 L and written in `\SI` like `\SI{100.000}{L}`.

While that I would like my decimal separator split with comma like for example 50,4 l and written in `\SI` like `\SI{50,4}{l}`.

Is that possible?
Currently I got this in my preamble for `\SI` coding

```
\usepackage{siunitx}                        
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}
```

Obviously I need something else to make the thousand separator happening with period and not comma.

Thanks!

Regards 
Andreas Skov

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-ignore={.},
         group-separator = {.},
         input-decimal-markers={,}, 
         output-decimal-marker = {,}}

\begin{document}
\SI{100.000}{\liter}

\SI{50,4}{\liter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `group-separator = {.}`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}                        
\sisetup{
    output-decimal-marker = {,},
    group-separator = {.}
}

\begin{document}

\SI{100000.000}{\litre}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: If you like the separator also for 1.000 l, you need to adjust `group-minimum-digits = 4`.